# Map.addLayer automation

Tags: google-earth-engine, string, band, for-loop

As in the [Hillshade Example](https://code.earthengine.google.com/861e7b0fb100aeae8303b05513ed7dab), I wanted to automate adding all Layer from one Image for visual inspection.

```
var band_names =Image.bandNames()
print(ee.String(band_names.get(0)))
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) { 
  Map.addLayer(Image.select(ee.String(band_names.get(i))), {}, ee.String(band_names.get(i)));
}
```

This returns the longest Error ever, not gonna post it entirely
[image]

2 Questions:

1. the Layer name is a String:

   ```
   print(ee.String(band_names.get(0)))
   ```

   yields a string. What's wrong with this code?
2. How do I call the number of Bands for the automation? I imagine something like :

   ```
   ee.Number(ee.Image.bad
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a computed object for the layer name, only literal strings.
You can download all of the band names from the server into a list of strings using getInfo(), and then it would work.

```
var band_names = Image.bandNames().getInfo()
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) { 
    Map.addLayer(Image.select(band_names[i]), {}, band_names[i]);
}
```